# Checkbox value in VBA yes/no

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form where I have a combobox and 4 checkboxes. I want to insert value from combobox and from chechboxes, when it is checked it is true and when not it is false.

When I put check on checkbox should insert value YES in database and when I don't put check it will be NO.

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim myval As String

If Me.Check2 Or Me.Check6 Or Me.Check8 Or Me.Check10 = -1 Then
myval = "Yes"
Else
myval = "No"

strSQL = "INSERT INTO Declaratie (Код_предр, Декларация, Данные_фирмы,   
Список_траспрота, Список_водителей) " & _
         " VALUES ('" & Me.НаимПредпр & "','" & Me.Check2 & "','" & Me.Check6 & "','" 
& Me.Check8 & "','" & Me.Check10 & "')"

Call AttServ(strSQL, rst) 'выполнение запроса
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add some information about problem itself...

Comment: when i put check on checkbox should insert value YES in database and when i don't put check it will be NO

Comment: How many checkboxes need to be filled in before you insert it, only 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply format a YesNo (boolean) control to get a Yes or a No, but this is probably not such a good idea. You would be better storing the YesNo as it is in a YesNo field and just formatting your form to show a Yes or No. Note that the code below will not work with a YesNo data type, because you are storing text.

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO Declaratie (Код_предр, Декларация, Данные_фирмы,   
    Список_траспрота, Список_водителей) " & _
             " VALUES ('" & Me.НаимПредпр & "','" _
             & Format(Me.Check2, "Yes/No") & "','" _
             & Format(Me.Check6, "Yes/No") & "','" 
             & Format(Me.Check8, "Yes/No") & "','" _
             & Format(Me.Check10, "Yes/No") & "')"

    Call AttServ(strSQL, rst) 'выполнение запроса
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If Me.Check2.VALUE = 1 Then
myval = "Yes"
Else
myval = "No"
END IF
```

Add this code to every check box, cause as i know that you cannot using a code to made all checkbox or radiobutton do same thing. You must using a checkbox or radiobutton own code even it's same

Comment: what is the wrong result?
Cause i was using VB.net, so maybe get some wrong. And how many need to check to get the YES value,

Comment: I am afraid VB.Net is not at all like VBA. A checkbox in MS Access will contain -1 or 0, never 1.